# How to set which entities a workflow for Content Moderation applies to?

Tags: 8, entities, workflows

On Drupal 8.3, I enabled the Content Moderation and Workflow modules.

This provides an example **Editorial Workflow** by default.

[image: workflow screen]

The [Content Moderation documentation states](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/content-moderation/overview):

> Once your moderation workflows are established, you can apply the
>   workflows to different entity types. Out of the box Content Moderation
>   can be added to Block Content and Content (Node) entities. The
>   "select" button will allow you to select which types should use this
>   workflow.

However, there is no "select" link on the workflow edit page.  The screenshot on the documentation page shows *This workflow applies to*, but out of the box that information is not displayed.

**Where can I select which types of entities a workflow applies to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported from Core 8.4, so you have to upgrade your site.  Then it shows up in the UI normally.